# zsh doesn't use my $PATH correct

Tags: bash, path, zsh, oh-my-zsh, dotfiles

I try to ran a script from `~/.dotfiles/bin`, but `zsh` doesn't got it instead the bash:

```
➜  ~  cat ~/.dotfiles/bin/dotfiles-test 
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hello world'
➜  ~  echo $PATH
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/:~/.dotfiles/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
➜  ~  dotfiles-test
zsh: command not found: dotfiles-test
➜  ~  bash
bash-3.2$ source .exports 
bash-3.2$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/:~/.dotfiles/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin/:~/.dotfiles/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
bash-3.2$ dotfiles-test 
hello world
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Is did you remember to `chmod +x dotfiles-test` ?

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `~/.dotfiles/bin` to `$HOME/.dotfiles/bin`.